# Combine Checbox wtih Text Field in PHP

Tags: php, forms, for-loop

I'm try to combine a checkbox values with a text field into one variable, so that when I echo it out it shows the correct fields values.

I want to combine the post of the checkbox with that of the quantity text field, because there are several items i'm using a forloop but can't seem to combine both values into one so that it creates a new table row with that item name on the left and the quantity on the right.

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_stitle', true); ?>" />
   </td>

   <td>
      <input id="quantity" name="check[quantity]" type="text" maxlength="3" /><br />
   </td>
```

```
  $data = $_POST['check'];
        foreach ($data as $value) {
        $item .= '<tr style="background: #eee;">
                <td>Item: </td>
                <td>'.$value.'</td>
            </tr>';
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably change:

```
<input id="quantity" name="check[quantity]" type="text" maxlength="3" /><br />
```

to:

```
<input id="quantity" name="check[quantity][]" type="text" maxlength="3" /><br />
```

You scalar your checkbox but not the textfield.

Also, it would probably simpler to relate your two fields with a for, as the array key's will be the same between each checkbox and input field.

Example:

```
for($i=0;$i<=sizeof($_POST['check'])-2;$i++){
    $item .= '<tr style="background: #eee;">
            <td>Item: '.$_POST['check'][$i].'</td>
            <td>'.$_POST['check']['quantity'][$i].'</td>
        </tr>';
}
```

Also, note the -2 from sizeof $_POST. You must subtract both your quantity key and your offset to set your ending point equal to that since you are counting from 0.

Comment: Thanks you, sixeightzero that was once of the fastest replies I've ever gotten, I had to modified the for code a little to get to work into: for ($i=0; $i <=sizeof($_POST['check']) - 2; $i++ )